# What are all the "-core" genres in metal other than metalcore, deathcore, and grindcore?

Tags: metal

I know there are several but I'm looking for a definitive list of all the genres that end in -core. Love 'em or hate 'em, they're here to stay. I'm asking here because r/metal and other metal forums aren't female or -core fan friendly.

Comment: I started out DJing Hardcore/Happy Hardcore at 16 - very different style of music, though. I wonder what makes things "core". I wish I could think of a better way to phrase that question.

Comment: @n00dles At least for the kind of "core" you mentioned here, it's basically just tempo. All of the Hardcore genres are about 170/180+ bpm. Unless you want to count Hardstyle as Hardcore subgenre as well, which is basically a slow version of Mainstyle Gabber (it originally grew out of Hardtrance but has little in common with it anymore these days). Also, there's other high bpm genres in the Psy scene that are usually not considered Hardcore, like Dark Psy, Forest, Hi-Tech or Psycore, so I guess that may not be the only criterium.

Comment: @n00dles I'd say it's basically anything that grew out of early 90s Rave music, which focused on higher bpm and stronger kicks. Don't ask me how Breakcore fits in there, though. As for a more general statement, as the term Hardcore basically mentions, it's music whose core focus is being hard, however that may be achieved.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher Yeah, I'd never split stuff into genres when I DJ'd. If it sounded good in the set, I'd put it in. I liked breaking up a set with them. Especially going harder towards the end. Quite often I'd speed up Hardstyle and hard trance to ~180 in a hardcore set. If it sounded good, it was fair game! _"What genre do you play?"_ - Well... fast and hard dance muzik! - All the "cores" and "hards"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really an infinite number of genres, you can create one yourself, imo. Some other recognizable -cores are electronicore, mathcore, prog metalcore, although they are arguably subgenres of metalcore. You will find a lot of punk-metalcore crossovers to make new core subgenres. r/metalcore might be a good place for you.

Comment: Are there any other sites like this that are female friendly? I mean I love metalcore and deathcore but I hate when people on those forums automatically assume that I'm a male and when I reveal my true identity I get a lot of negative feedback on it. Even here. I want a place where people can say "Oh, SHE loves metal!"

Comment: r/metalmemes is nice, r/progrock r/progmetal etc all are really nice. I have noticed only r/metal being quite elitist. Also unfortunately, people will always assume you're a male, not because they are bad, but because there's an overwhelmingly large male population in these subs. But you should join and be more active, so other females who may be on the same page as you, will find it easier to join! hope to see you there!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is a fairly definitive list, plus some extras: [List of hardcore punk subgenres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hardcore_punk_subgenres).

However, new subgenres are always being created. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

These are all the metalcore subgenres, that came to my mind. I know I'm bit late, but if you see this post and still interested in more core genres, I might make additional lists for post-hardcore, screamo, deathcore and/or grindcore.

Metalcore:

- Ambient Metalcore.
- Beatdown Metal.
- Blackened Metalcore.
- Brutal Metalcore (H8000/Edge Metal).
- Chaotic Hardcore.
- Crossover Thrash (sometimes considered as a core style, but more often thought as a punkier thrash metal).
- Dark Metalcore.
- Djentcore.
- Electronicore.
- Entombedcore.
- Gothcore.
- Heavy Hardcore (It's not really a style of metalcore, but it is a core genre).
- Holy Terror (yes! It is a real genre :D).
- Mathcore.
- Melodic Metalcore.
- Metallic Hardcore (later variant. Earlier variant is just metal influenced punk).
- Moshcore.
- Nintendocore.
- Nu Metalcore.
- Post-Metalcore.
- Powercore.
- Progressive Metalcore.
- Scenecore.
- Sludgecore (metalcore variant. Hardcore variant is commonly known as sludge punk).
- Southern Hardcore.
- Technical Hardcore.
- Thrash (Metal)core (Thrashcore term is more often used on aggressive, often high tempo, thrashy hardcore punk, with no relation to metal, which is why this genre is also often called as groove thrash and gothenthrash).
- Trancecore (minor difference from electronicore being bigger influence from trance music).

Answer (score 0):

Sadcore is a prevalent enough music genre to warrant its own Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadcore

Answer (score 0):

Some of the ones that have not been mentioned here : Aliencore (rings of saturn),
Emotive Hardcore, Post Hardcore (check out fugazi for the OG) theres even people starting to use the term Blackcore. Anyway, I'm here because I am creating a youtube playlist called "All the Cores" and I'm looking for other -core genres other than what I know of.